# sslsocket session mecanism for high latency connexion

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I want to use **SSLSocket over a high latency connexion**. The **SSL Handshake** requires several roundtrip, it will be causing a high delay before being able to work this the socket.
It becomes a **bottleneck** when I need a lot of short socket communication.

Of course the alternative whould be implementing VirtualSocket over Socket but I think this approach was deprecated in some famous frameworks making me think it is quite tricky...

In JAVA 6, **is there a session mecanism** allowing the user to open a second socket without handshaking again? How to configure this?

I would have liked to code a test by myself but I do not have access to the production environment (where high latency occurs) and don't know about socket latency simulation tools.

Thanks for your help,

Renaud

Comment: I assume you can't use a connection pool?

Comment: It is difficult to reuse a connection because I cannot guaranty that the "user" (client or server) of the socket will leave it in a consistant way (for instance with no unread datas in the socket buffer). Closing the socket and opening a new one would be far easier if a session mecanism is implemented.

Comment: You could test the connection to determine if it is good before adding it to the pool.

Comment: how would you do that? how to recover connection integrity on both hands? mmhh sounds like using a strange protocol with magic number exchange... not efficient on my high latency context.

Comment: Send one request which expect a specific response.  You won't get any faster than that. It can be done in the background before adding to the pool so the latency is not apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSSE SSL Session mechanism works automatically as long as the peer supports it as well. Make sure the SSL Session timeout at the peer is set to a reasonable value for your purpose, such as 15 minutes.

Comment: Can you point me to a documentation about this? I cannot find details about that on Oracle JSSE documentation.
Thanks!

Comment: @NumRenaud See javax.net.ssl.SSLSession